# deployed application appears different in IE8

Tags: asp.net, html, css, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

I developed an application locally using the Visual Studio 2008 built-in web server and it is running nice and neat on every single browser.

When we deployed it on the IIS6 and open it on IE8, there are rendering issues. The fonts are bigger than the other browsers (which are still nice and neat) and some components just moved around. The generated HTML is the same as the others.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are default browser stylesheets getting in the way? Make sure you've explicitly set the font size and family that you want to use.  Other than that, I don't think you've given us much to work with.

Comment: **1.** Could you show the doctype you're using? (show first few lines)  **2.** Could you tell me what you write in the Address Bar of your browser when you access your site when it's on IIS6?

Comment: The doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: The remote link: http://poweredge:82/grapes/Paginas/OT/Default.aspx

Comment: Felipe, people in the internet cannot access your LOCAL server!

Comment: Guttsy, the font size and family are explicitly set on the global CSS

Comment: @Diodeus: He provided the "remote link" because I asked him to. There was a reason I asked, and it's not so I can look at his site :) It's to do with IE's rules of jumping into Quirks Mode depending on the type of URL you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Diodeus and thirtydot we figured out how to solve the problem.

The meta tag "X-UA-Compatible" allow you to control  the way Internet Explorer interprets and displays your webpage. when i set  , it overrides the ie7 rendering mode that IIS 6.0  puts IE 8.0 into.

Here is some useful information about that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. Which DOCType are you using - are you in "quirks mode" or "standards mode"?
2. Are you using a CSS reset?
3. Are you using the IE7 compatibility tag?

There are ways to fix what's "wrong" but without seeing your code, determining what's wrong is difficult.

[image: IEMode]

Press F-12 in IE8 and see what browser mode you are in. If you're in "quirks mode" you're in trouble.

Comment: It seems ISS is ignoring the doctype. I changed it to the HTML5 doctype and running it locally the browser rendered the page a little messy but on the IIS nothing changed... Why???

Comment: IIS doesn't even "see" the doctype, the browser does. See the image I'm embedding in my answer.